# How can I configure gem install to use "install" from the right place?

Tags: configuration, rubygems, symlink

When I try to install rails using gem on my Arch Linux machine, I get the following error:

> $ gem install rails
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> make install
>
> /usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 bcrypt_ext.so /home/gphilip/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib
>
> make: /usr/bin/install: Command not found
>
> make: *** [/home/gphilip/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/lib/bcrypt_ext.so] Error 127

It turns out that on Arch Linux, the "install" binary [is located at /bin/install](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=322054%20buha). So on my system I have:

> $which install
>
> /bin/install
>
> $

Since I have root access (it is my laptop!), I could easily "fix" this by creating a symlink at /usr/bin/install , but how would I do this otherwise?

> How do I configure gem to use the "install" command from /bin/ instead of insisting on using the one in /usr/bin/ ?

I am asking this in case I am in a situation where I face the same problem and I don't have permissions to create symlinks in arbitrary places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find `rbconfig.rb` file in your ruby installation dir (example for my machine):

```
$ which ruby
/home/valentin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/bin/ruby

$ find /home/valentin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352 -name rbconfig.rb
/home/valentin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb
```

In that file change line

```
CONFIG["INSTALL"] = '/usr/bin/install -c'
```

to

```
CONFIG["INSTALL"] = '/bin/install -c'
```

(Or whichever is the correct install path, I've had to change it back to `/usr/bin`, for example)

You might want to update other paths as well.

Or, you can just reinstall ruby.